# How to use an arb file from inside another arb file and from an rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an active admin ruby file (file_one.rb) which render some data using the syntax from the documentation (index do... end).
Also, I have another active admin ruby file, that uses an arb file (_big_arb_file.html.arb) for its show method. Part of the info that this renders is a nested object that is the same as the one from file_one.rb as above. What I tried to do was to:

1. create an arb partial with only the common code from the _big_arb_file.html.arb
2. use the new arb partial from inside the _big_arb_file.html.arb
3. use the new arb partial from inside the file_one.rb index do...end method

I couldn't make it work cause I cannot find how to pass in the data/object from inside index do...end to the render 'new_arb.html.arb' with_object: the_data_here

I am new to ruby and rails, so I apologise if I am using the wrong terminology. Also, I am happy to share some code for demo purposes if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of passing a local into a nested ARB partial:

`app/views/orders/_show.arb:`

```
columns do
  ...
  column do
    render 'payment_methods/panel', payment_method: order.payment_method
  end
end
```

`app/views/payment_methods/_panel.arb`

```
payment_method = local_assigns[:payment_method]
panel do
  ...
```